# Do all thermal radiators have the same surface brightness?

Tags: radiation, thermal-radiation, geometric-optics

Imagine I heat a piece of metal to 1000K. It will be red hot and will emit black body radiation corresponding to this temperature.

But what about the brightness? Assuming the bulk is opaque, does it matter whether I heat and iron or a wolfram piece? Both will have the same color, but which one will be brighter when I look at it?

Comment: "Imagine I heat a piece of metal to 1000K. It will be red hot and will emit black body radiation" That's not true; metals are not black bodies. Check, for example, the Wikipedia page on black body radiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total power radiated is given by the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law):

$$ j = \varepsilon \sigma T^4 $$

where $\varepsilon$ is the [emissivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity) and this varies from object to object. A perfect black body has $\varepsilon=1$ at all wavelengths, but real surfaces will have $\varepsilon\lt 1$ over at least part of the spectrum.

Offhand I don't know how the emissivity of iron and tungsten compare, but I would guess they are pretty similar so they will have a similar brightness at 1000K. It will depend a lot on the surface finish. Highly polished surfaces with a high reflectivity will have low emissivities (the emissivity + the reflectivity always add up to one). So a dull iron surface will glow more brightly than a polished tungsten surface and *vice versa*.

A quick Google will find you [emissivities for various different materials](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=emissivity%20table).

Comment: There's also a wavelength dependence to the emissivity which is ignored in the Stefan-Boltzmann expression above and also in most tables which give wavelength-averaged values for the emissivities of various materials. If iron and tungsten have different wavelength dependencies to their emissivities, they may appear to be radiating light at slightly different colors even when they are at the same temperature.

Comment: @SamuelWeir: oops yes, in practice the total energy would be an integral involving $\varepsilon(\lambda)$ or $\varepsilon(\nu)$. If you want to expand that into an answer I'll delete my answer.

Comment: No, your answer is perfectly fine. I just wanted to add that there may be a wavelength dependence to the emissivity. I believe that it is generally small. Tungsten, as I recall, has an emissivity that varies about only 5% throughout the visible range. So it's a small effect but important if you're doing something like precise temperature measurements by multi-channel pyrometry. However, for many other purposes the wavelength dependence of the emissivity can probably be ignored.

Comment: I think the emissivity of polished metals at wavelengths corresponding to the visible range is generally much higher than in the infra red range. The latter being the one displayed in most tables if I'm not wrong.

Comment: So a perfect reflector would never cool down?

Comment: @Calmarius: correct, or at least it would never cool by radiation - it could still cool by convection and conduction. Of course the corollary is that it would never heat up either.